# bidicontour and \is@RTL

Tags: xetex

I am trying to use XeLaTeX and bidicontour. My minimal example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidicontour}
\begin{document}
  \bidicontour{red}{foo}
\end{document}
```

and I am getting this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\@bidicontour ...r@outline {#2}{#3}\else \if@RTL 
                                              \mbox {#3}\fi \begingroup
```

Comment: I have no idea what `bidicontour` does but `\usepackage{bidicontour,bidi}` works without error on your test

Comment: I am now tryinig to find what debian package includes bidi.sty...,  @DavidCalisle, want to post the official answer?

Comment: Package texlive-lang-arabic for debian distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `bidi` or any package which use `bidi` like `xepersian`  after `bidicontour`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidicontour}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
  \bidicontour{red}{foo}
\end{document}
```